# navbar dropdown, navbar login link does not work but the dropdown menu links do

Tags: html, django, drop-down-menu, navbar

Good morning community

I am building my first application in Django and I have a problem with the navbar. The "login link" placed in the navbar does go to the URL when I click on it. The links that are on the dropdown menu work just fine. Any hints?

Hereunder is my code,

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/login" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Login
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout">Logout</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'simple_investing:register' %}">Register</a>                    
      </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: What you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: When I click it it does not go to the Login url.

Comment: Do you really want to toggle the dropdown when clicking on that login button?

Comment: Well I would like to be able to click on the login button as well as to have a dropdown menu on it. Is that possible?

Comment: Yeah, that would be possible, but it sounds weird..